# Why am I getting relation already exists in this execute statement?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, execute

Here's the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_img(ptype text, pid integer, pdpi integer)
  RETURNS bytea AS
$BODY$
declare psize char(1); pimg bytea;
begin
    select size into psize from dpi_size where dpi in(select max(dpi) from dpi_size where dpi <= pdpi);
    select coalesce(psize, 's') into psize;

    if ptype = 'cat' then
        execute 'select img_' || psize || ' into pimg from cat where id = $1' using pid;
    end if;

    return pimg;

end; $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION get_img(text, integer, integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Table cat has img_s, img_m, img_l and an id. Here's what I get when I run select.

```
select handyman_get_img ('cat', 11, 320)
```

> ERROR:  relation "pimg" already exists CONTEXT:  SQL statement "select
>   img_l into pimg from cat where id = $1" PL/pgSQL function
>   get_img(text,integer,integer) line 8 at EXECUTE statement

Can anyone enlighten me why it says 'pimg' already exists?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a variable inside the string literal for `execute`.

The string passed to `execute` is run "as is" and `select .. into pimg from ...` is [an old (non-standard) syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-selectinto.html) that does the same as `create table pimg as select ...`.

If you want to store the result of an `execute` into a variable you need to use a different syntax:

```
execute 'select img_' || psize || ' from cat where id = $1' 
        into pimg
        using pid;
```

Note how the `into` is outside of the string that is being executed.

Comment: Thanks. Your format works. However, if select into creates a temp table, how come the 'already exists' error doesn't come up when I don't use an 'execute' statement, and just write select img_l into pimg where...?

Comment: @Sebouh: because the first `select` is not a string literal but an "embedded" select which is executed by the PL/pgSQL engine - which understands that the `into` is used for a variable not a new table.